# Taylor series expansion, radius of conversion

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

I am stuck on expanding this function with Maclaurin series:

$$\ f(x) = \frac{1}{2+3x^2} $$

I have calculate the first derivatives and evaluated them at zero:

$$\ f'(x)= -\frac{6x}{(2+3x^2)^2} \\ f''(x) = -\frac{6(2-3x^2)}{(2+3x^2)^2} $$

and stopped at $ f^{IV}(0) = -\frac{308}{27}$ - I suppose I am wrong

Therefore I obtain the beginning:

$$\ f(x) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{3}{2}x^2 +... $$

For me it looks like:

$$\ \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{(k+1)x^n}{2^{n+2}} $$

but simultaneously, it looks for me utterly wrong and I would appreciate the hint, how to expand the series and find the radius.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calculating derivatives, try to restate it in terms of a series you know.
$$\frac1{2+3x^2}=\frac12\frac1{1+\frac{3x^2}2}$$
Now if you set $y=\sqrt\frac32x$ you'll see an expression with a familiar series that has radius of convergence $1$, so you just have to restate $|y|<1$ in terms of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that\begin{align}f(x)&=\frac1{2+3x^2}\\&=\frac12\times\frac1{1+\frac32x^2}\\&=\frac12\left(1-\frac32x^2+\frac{3^2}{2^2}x^4-\frac{3^3}{2^3}x^6+\cdots\right)\text{ if }\left|\frac32x^2\right|<1\\&=\frac12-\frac3{2^2}x^2+\frac{3^2}{2^3}x^4-\frac{3^3}{2^4}x^6+\cdots\end{align}It is now easy to see that the radius of convergence is $\sqrt{\frac23}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Rewrite $$\ f(x) = \frac{1}{2+3x^2}=\frac 12 \times\frac 1 {1+\frac 32 x^2}$$ Now, let $t=\frac 32 x^2$.

Expand in terms of $t$ and, when done, replace $t$ and simplify.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $f(x)= \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{1-(-\frac{3}{2}x^2)}.$

Now geometric seies !